# Remove keys() while loading matlab files in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, key

I am tryin to load a matlab file in python and  i have written these lines:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as spio

f = np.load('adj_data.npy',allow_pickle = True)
array1 = np.array(f)
print(array1)
print(type(array1))
```

After running this code i get these results:

```
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Wed Feb 07 15:26:44 2018', '__version__': '1.0', '__globals__': [], 'A': array([[[0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00],
        [1.76007e-02, 2.65923e+00, 3.36400e-01, 3.66851e-02],
        [1.47450e-01, 1.98776e+00, 9.35137e-02, 1.11462e-02],
        ...,
        [0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00],
        [2.56731e-01, 2.77940e+00, 3.76996e-01, 1.92662e-02],
        [1.54293e-02, 2.99425e+00, 6.52976e-01, 3.54300e-02]],

       [[1.76007e-02, 2.65923e+00, 3.36400e-01, 3.66851e-02],
        [0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00],
        [1.65050e-01, 6.71471e-01, 2.42886e-01, 2.55389e-02],
        ...,
        [1.76007e-02, 2.65923e+00, 3.36400e-01, 3.66851e-02],
        [2.74331e-01, 1.20168e-01, 4.05960e-02, 5.59513e-02],
        [2.17143e-03, 3.35016e-01, 3.16577e-01, 1.25509e-03]],

       [[1.47450e-01, 1.98776e+00, 9.35137e-02, 1.11462e-02],
        [1.65050e-01, 6.71471e-01, 2.42886e-01, 2.55389e-02],
        [0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00],
        ...,
        [1.47450e-01, 1.98776e+00, 9.35137e-02, 1.11462e-02],
        [1.09281e-01, 7.91639e-01, 2.83482e-01, 3.04123e-02],
        [1.62879e-01, 1.00649e+00, 5.59462e-01, 2.42838e-02]]])}


       <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

How can i can remove the first part of the array or keys() part of matlab array:

```
 {'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Wed Feb 07 15:26:44 2018', '__version__': '1.0', '__globals__': [], 'A':
```

Comment: That is not an array, that is a `dict`. One of it's keys, `'A'` is mapped to an array. Are you asking how to get a value from a dict?

Comment: I just want to print a simple array [ ] with numbers inside it, to remove the first part of keys() attribute. But when i print the type, it's not a ```dict``` but ````numpy array````

Comment: Because you did `array1 = np.array(f)`. Not sure why you expected that to work, `f` is a dictionary. Don't do `array1 = np.array(f)`. Just **use the dictionary**. Again, are you asking how to use a dictionary? There is no `.keys()` attribute here, I'm not sure what you mean when it comes to matlab. Again, `f` is a dict, so just access the array inside the dict at key `'A'`

Comment: keys() are considered all attributes that can be extracted from the ```dict``` starting with `A`, `_version_` etc. I want to take only the array part ```A``` part and i am using this code: ```r = f['A']``` but i get a new error

Comment: That dictionary looks like it came from `spio.loadmat('something.mat').  But you show a `np.load` call.  Did someone `loadmat` and the `np.save` it?  I wonder we are seeing an object array wrapper around the dict?

Comment: numpy files or npy files are extracted from matlab files, they still have the same format and keys but you cannot extract keys as you generally do with normal matlab files so this didn't give me any error: ```import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio


array1 = sio.loadmat('subject1_tensor.mat', squeeze_me=True)

x = array1["my_array"]```  
where my_array is the array i want to extract from my matlab file

Answer (score 0):

If it is matlab `.mat` file (seems to be), use:

```
import scipy.io as sio

array1 = sio.loadmat('adj_data.npy', mat_dtype = True)['A']
```

Comment: I tried this but i am getting an Index Error now: ```IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices```

Comment: From the posted data, it looks like the key is `A`. Might be you have not saved the file correctly. In fact, it should be `file.mat`. Did you save it from Matlab?